# facebook open graph : custom object submission error

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When I use the following to post an action to FB

```
curl -F 'access_token=AAAFxEPEoxQgBAGCUyzmyKGDJLoKe2uz1I823Uf8CUBfMagfrqvkRgNcif2ipJGDeNZBc9JBao1xB2pulEggmLF4wFC3HU8wqkWZAc3zAZDZD' \
 -F 'topic=http://myurl.com/467564296596508' \
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me/customapp:custom'
```

I get

```
Object at URL http://myurl.com/467564296596508 has og:type of 'website'. The property 'topic' requires an object of og:type 'customapp:custom'.
```

Source code of http://myurl.com/467564296596508

```
<html>
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# customapp: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/customapp#">
    <title>Content Title</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Content Title" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://myurl.com/img_default.png" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Custom App Heading" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="405792556107016" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://myurl.com/467564296596508" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="customapp:custom" />

</head>
<body>
</html>
```

How do I remove this error?

Regards
Ajay

Comment: If you’d given us the real URL instead of a fake one, maybe we could have a look …

Comment: it worked. my bad. no sleep for smtime